# Is it possible to make pathlib to treat trailing slash in a Path as significant?

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, pathlib, trailing-slash

There has been multiple discussions about the issue when dealing with trailing slashes in `pathlib.Path`, on Unix systems in particular such as https://bugs.python.org/issue21039 and https://bugs.python.org/issue39140.

Given the `pathlib.Path` constructed from a string, I wonder what would be the best way to make sure a trailing slash is preserved in the `Path` object the same way the `os` module does it?

```
>>> os.path.dirname("/a/b/")
'/a/b'
>>> os.path.dirname("/a/b")
'/a'
```

`os` module understands the difference between `"/a/b/"` and `"/a/b"`, but `pathlib` doesn't:

```
>>> Path("/a/b/").parent
PosixPath('/a')
```

Is there any way to be able to differentiate between paths that are pointing to a file (without a trailing slash) and to a directory (that has a trailing slash)? Or I'd have to switch to using `os` module in this particular case?

If it's not possible, what would be a reasonable workaround to take advantage of `pathlib` and deal with the trailing slash issue?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a low-level path manipulation, I would go with the `os` module (as suggested by the pathlib [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html))

This would add the trailing slash, OS independently:

```
os.path.join(os.path.abspath("/a/b/"), "")
```